# Ошибка получения json кода в jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Если будет ссылка https://.../profile то все отлично работает и выводит, если https://.../profile/?code=... то выводит ошибку

````
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (profile.js:9)```
````

а вот код из js файла

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "engine/jquery/profile.php",
    data: {
        loader: true
    },
    success:function(response) {
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        $('#login').html(response.login);
        $('#mylogin').html(response.login);
        $("#avatar").attr("src", response.avatar);
        $("#myavatar").attr("src", response.avatar);
        $('#mail').html(response.mail);
        $('#group').html(response.group);
        $('#datareg').html(response.datareg);
        $('.preloader').fadeOut().fadeOut('slow');
    },
    error:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Возвращается html вместо JSON-а. Вероятно, в php происходит ошибка.

Comment: Исправил php файл что-то напрямую json файл выдавало в запросов в базу данных, тоже самое

Comment: Вижу, использовал лог в консоль и посмотрел что выводит действительно html

Answer (score 1):

Решил, указывал не полный путь к файлу, и по переходу по этому файлу его перебрасывало на индексированную страницу и мне выводил код